# SVG draw text HTML5

Tags: html, svg, draw

i'm very interested in this text effect:

here is the demo link: https://codemyui.com/merry-christmas-svg-text-animation/

here is the source: https://gist.github.com/CodeMyUI/a5643c7953a007cfb1634a2f8b35541e

so, it now is "merry chrismast"! how can i edit this SVG text :)

for example:

```
this one: <path d="M86.61 290.78l-9 16.32c-.6 1.08-1.8 1.8-3.06 1.8-1.32 0-2.46-.72-3.06-1.8l-9-16.32V317c0 1.74-1.5 3.18-3.18 3.18-1.74 0-3.18-1.44-3.18-3.18v-36.6c0-1.92 1.62-3.48 3.48-3.48 1.38 0 2.52.78 3.12 1.86l11.82 21.12 11.82-21.12c.6-1.08 1.86-1.86 3.12-1.86 1.92 0 3.48 1.56 3.48 3.48V317c0 1.74-1.5 3.18-3.24 3.18-1.68 0-3.12-1.44-3.12-3.18v-26.22z"/>
== character "M"
```

Thank you so much :)

Comment: Find an SVG edit and create the path you want. Inkscape or SVG-edit perhaps.

Comment: really, tks you, i''ll try

Comment: @RobertLongson sir, it return : |
<g>
  <title>Layer 1</title>
  <text stroke="#000000" xml:space="preserve" text-anchor="middle" font-family="serif" font-size="24" id="svg_1" y="25" x="83" stroke-width="0" fill="#000000">s2DevTeam.com</text>
 </g>

is not same what i expected

Comment: looks like you've not drawn a path.

Comment: @RobertLongson opp, i don't know about svg T.T tks you, i'll try again

Comment: @RobertLongson i tried with Inkscape and it returned:
<path
                    d="m 46.082582,111.08493 q 0,1.0542 -0.875054,1.72944 -0.868164,0.67524 -2.377116,0.67524 -0.854384,0 -1.570963,-0.19982 -0.70969,-0.2067 -1.192003,-0.44786 v -1.45383 h 0.0689 q 0.613227,0.46164 1.364258,0.73725 0.751031,0.26872 1.44005,0.26872 0.854384,0 1.336697,-0.27561 0.482313,-0.27561 0.482313,-0.8......"
                    style="font-size:14.11111069px;stroke-width:0.26458332"
                    id="path3688"/>

so, i paste but no thing display @@

Comment: @RobertLongson tks you :) i have done perfectly